# Crypto++ ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey::Initialize make a segmentation fault [SOLVED]

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, crypto++

I have a program that initialize an ECDSA key pair and store them. That program worked, but now, I have a segmentation fault when initializing an ECDSA Private key using the Crypto++ library.

Here is what I am doing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cryptopp/eccrypto.h>
#include <cryptopp/osrng.h>
#include <cryptopp/oids.h>
#include <cryptopp/files.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if(argc < 2)
    {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " key_name" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PrivateKey privateKey;
    AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    privateKey.Initialize(prng, ASN1::secp256r1());
    bool result = privateKey.Validate(prng, 3);
    if(!result)
        return 2;

    ECDSA<ECP, SHA256>::PublicKey publicKey;
    privateKey.MakePublicKey(publicKey);

    result = publicKey.Validate(prng, 3);
    if(!result)
        return 3;

    FileSink fsppk(string(string(argv[1]) + ".ppk").c_str(), true /*binary*/);
    privateKey.Save(fsppk);
    fsppk.Flush(true);

    FileSink fspub(string(string(argv[1]) + ".pub").c_str(), true /*binary*/);
    publicKey.Save(fspub);
    fspub.Flush(true);

    return 0;
}
```

I use crypto++-8.2.0.3 and I have the segmentation fault either with clang 11.0.0 and g++ 10.2.0.

QtCreator tells me that the fault comes in the delete in this function from smartptr.h:

```
template <class T> value_ptr<T>& value_ptr<T>::operator=(const value_ptr<T>& rhs)
{
    T *old_p = this->m_p;
    this->m_p = rhs.m_p ? new T(*rhs.m_p) : NULLPTR;
    delete old_p;
    return *this;
}
```

[EDIT] The stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7cbd813 in CryptoPP::value_ptr<CryptoPP::ECP>::operator= (this=0x7fffffffdd88, rhs=...) at smartptr.h:95
#1  0x00007ffff7cf483e in CryptoPP::EcPrecomputation<CryptoPP::ECP>::operator= (this=0x7fffffffdd78) at ecp.h:126
#2  CryptoPP::DL_GroupParametersImpl<CryptoPP::EcPrecomputation<CryptoPP::ECP>, CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::ECPPoint>, CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters<CryptoPP::ECPPoint> >::operator= (this=0x7fffffffdd68) at pubkey.h:1013
#3  CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP>::operator= (this=0x7fffffffdd68) at eccrypto.h:39
#4  0x00007ffff7d07272 in CryptoPP::GetValueHelperClass<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP>, CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters<CryptoPP::ECPPoint> >::Assignable (this=0x7fffffffd260)
    at algparam.h:197
#5  CryptoPP::GetValueHelperClass<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP>, CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters<CryptoPP::ECPPoint> >::Assignable (this=0x7fffffffd260) at algparam.h:189
#6  CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP>::GetVoidValue (pValue=0x7fffffffdd68, valueType=..., name=<optimized out>, this=<optimized out>) at eccrypto.cpp:510
#7  CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP>::GetVoidValue (this=<optimized out>, name=<optimized out>, valueType=..., pValue=0x7fffffffdd68) at eccrypto.cpp:497
#8  0x00007ffff7cdce12 in CryptoPP::NameValuePairs::GetValue<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP> > (value=..., name=<optimized out>, this=0x7fffffffd950) at cryptlib.h:379
#9  CryptoPP::NameValuePairs::GetThisObject<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP> > (object=..., this=0x7fffffffd950) at cryptlib.h:359
#10 CryptoPP::DL_PrivateKeyImpl<CryptoPP::DL_GroupParameters_EC<CryptoPP::ECP> >::GenerateRandom (this=this@entry=0x7fffffffdd00, rng=..., params=...) at pubkey.h:1278
#11 0x00007ffff7d216ac in CryptoPP::DL_PrivateKey_WithSignaturePairwiseConsistencyTest<CryptoPP::DL_PrivateKey_EC<CryptoPP::ECP>, CryptoPP::ECDSA<CryptoPP::ECP, CryptoPP::SHA256> >::GenerateRandom (this=0x7fffffffdd00, rng=..., params=...) at pubkey.h:1321
#12 0x000055555555c5d6 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffe018) at ../../../pki/main.cpp:21
```

And, in QtCreator I have these messsages:

```
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CryptoPP::ECP' value
  found `CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::EC2NPoint>::~DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl()' instead
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CryptoPP::ECP' value
  found `CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::EC2NPoint>::~DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl()' instead
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CryptoPP::ECP' value
  found `CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::EC2NPoint>::~DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl()' instead
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CryptoPP::ECP' value
  found `CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::EC2NPoint>::~DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl()' instead
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CryptoPP::ECP' value
  found `CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::EC2NPoint>::~DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl()' instead
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CryptoPP::ECP' value
  found `CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::EC2NPoint>::~DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl()' instead
can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `CryptoPP::ECP' value
  found `CryptoPP::DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl<CryptoPP::EC2NPoint>::~DL_FixedBasePrecomputationImpl()' instead
```

[EDIT 2] Solution

I have found the solution: I had two version of the crypto++ in my /usr/lib/.

1. The 8.2.0 from repository,
2. 8.3.0 that I should build myself so long time ago that I can't remember this.

The libcryptopp.so.8 was pointing to the 8.3.0 version, by pointing to the 8.2.0 it work again.

Comment: Please create a full compilable [MCVE] including a short `int main()` function and all the relevant `#include`s?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the crash. I have the same version of crypto++, clang and g++. How do you compile the example (i.e. what flags are passed to the compiler)? I used e.g. `clang++ $( pkg-config --cflags --libs libcryptopp ) test.cpp` and the same for gcc. Also maybe it would be helpful if you could give a full stack trace.

Comment: I first compile with `clang++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC  -I../../../pki -I. -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-clang -o main.o ../../../pki/main.cpp` and `clang++ -ccc-gcc-name g++ -o pki main.o   -lcryptopp`. By setting QtCreator with pkg-config I have `clang++ -c -pipe -g -std=gnu++11 -Wall -Wextra -fPIC  -I../../../pki -I. -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/lib/qt/mkspecs/linux-clang -o main.o ../../../pki/main.cpp` and `clang++ -ccc-gcc-name g++ -o pki main.o   -L/usr/local/lib -lcryptopp`. I added the stacktrace in my edit.

Comment: @f9c69e9781fa194211448473495534 Thanks for your comment it permit me to think to try with ldd after and see that I had two versions of crypto++.